# Issues executing program

Tags: linux, debian, command-line, process, processes

Ultimately I'm trying to get a program to run at start up and work correctly.

I have been successful in getting it to show up in running processes after a reboot, but it doesn't seem like it is working correctly.

I started to troubleshoot the problem and I came across some interesting discoveries.

I am running openmediavault 1.0.20 which is based on Debian Wheezy and logged in as root with ssh.

Path to uTorrent install: `/opt/utorrent`

If I enter

```
cd /opt/utorrent          
./utserver
```

utserver runs and I'm able to to access the webui by server'sip:8080/gui

However when I run

```
cd /
/opt/utorrent/utserver
```

utserver runs but the web ui is not accessible. I don't understand why one way works and yet the other doesn't.

Once I can get the webui to work after running `/opt/utorrent/utserver` the modifications I made to `rc.local` should work correclty

Current contents of  rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#Auto run uTorrent at start up
#su ut -c '/opt/utorrent/utserver &'
sudo /opt/utorrent/utserver &


exit 0
```

Comment: It's possible that utserver looks for a configuration file in the directory it's started from. Something like "use from current directory, or else from user's home directory, or else hard-coded defaults" sounds reasonable, and maybe the defaults don't have the web interface enabled. The docs should be able to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use `sudo` in init scripts.  They're run as root to start with.
2. If you were to use `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local` (which as per #1 there is no point  in doing), you need to provide a `$PATH` or the path to the executable because there is no `$PATH` set when this is run at boot by `init`.  So, e.g., if you wanted to run `ls`, first find out where it is:

   > whereis ls
   >     ls: /usr/bin/ls /usr/share/man/man1p/ls.1p.gz /usr/share/man/man1/ls.1.gz

   So, you either need:

   ```
   export PATH=/usr/bin/  # At the top
   - OR -
   /usr/bin/ls   # Where you want to run it.
   ```

Beware that processes started from an init script **must background themselves**,   your

```
/opt/utorrent/utserver &
```

Should be fine.